# Why loopback 4 by default, doesnt support multiple insertion when I create Loopback 4 default REST CRUD controller?

Tags: loopback4

I loopback 3, I was able to insert multiple records at once but in loopback 4 default REST Controller with CRUD functions don't support this. I can use createAll instead of create and do little changes to achieve this but I am curious to know is there any specific reason to prevent multiple records creation at one go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One main reason could be that **`createAll()` isn't guaranteed atomic**. As the default Juggler ORM is shared between both LoopBack 3 and 4, this issue applies to both versions of LoopBack.

**The core explanation**

At a minimum, Juggler connectors need to implement the basic CRUD functions such as `create()` and `delete()`. In addition, connectors may also implement "compound" functions such as `createAll()` and `deleteAll()`.

However, not all connectors implement these "compound" functions. In these cases, Juggler will quietly create "stub" functions of the same name that wraps around the basic CRUD functions. For example, `createAll()` may just be a loop calling `create()` multiple times. This is useful as it means that developers can assume that those functions will exist. However, this breaks ACID compliance.

**What about transactions?**

Transactions are used to guarantee atomic operations based on a defined scope. However, not all connectors implement this - MongoDB being an example. Unlike "compound" functions, Juggler will not try to stub transactions. This means that the Transaction API may not exist for connectors that don't implement it.

**Why not throw an error?**

Throwing an error when `createAll()` isn't atomic or when the transactions API isn't implemented means that developers may need to write more integration tests to account for this possibility to provide database interoperability.

**TLDR;**

1. `createAll()` isn't guaranteed atomic without transactions.
2. Transactions aren't implemented in all connectors
3. It's not exposed in the default CRUD controller to encourage developers to understand the quirks of `createAll()` instead of just using it out-of-the-box and potentially shooting themselves in the foot.